# Re-order li elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, list

I have an li which shows location in an alphabetical order and I'd like to grab the elements of the list and return with a different order.

```
    <li class="single-contact-location">
      <span>Location</span> 
     ALocation, BLocation, CLocation, DLocation, ELocation, FLocation
    </li>
```

Let's say BLocation, ALocation, CLocation, DLocation, ELocation, FLocation

With

> var li =
>   document.getElementsByClassName("single-contact-location")[0];

I get the li class and the span with the locations but span confuses me because I cannot grab and reorder the elements.

Comment: you could split the string on a space and re-order it as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the location list by using the following code:

```js
/* querySelector: IE8+ support */
var span = document.querySelector(".single-contact-location > span");

/* get the next node after the span */
var textNodeAfterSpan = span.nextSibling;

/* Get the content of the text node and split it */
var locationList = textNodeAfterSpan.nodeValue.split(', ');

/* Reorder it */
var mainLocation = locationList[1];
locationList[1] = locationList[0];
locationList[0] = mainLocation;

/* Rewrite it */
textNodeAfterSpan.nodeValue = ' ' + locationList.join(', ');
```

```html
<li class="single-contact-location">
  <span>Location</span> 
  ALocation, BLocation, CLocation, DLocation, ELocation, FLocation
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you tzi for your reply but how can I show BLocation first and ALocation then? It's really good answer but reorders it randomly.

Comment: You just want to have the second one in the first place?

Comment: Yes, or the thrid one in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `childNode` property to grab those fields and modify accordingly. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sdvowy38/1/

```
 var li = document.getElementsByClassName("single-contact-location");
 var arr=li[0].childNodes[2].textContent.trim().split(',');
```